# how to load the default page after published angular2 app into azure web app?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, angular2-template, azure-web-app-service

I had developed simple angular 2 application by following this link. After that I published this application into azure web app successfully.

Next go to azure web app and click on browse option then it open web app like this below screenshot.

[image]

But I have published the angular2 application with index.cshtml page. Before publishing the angular2 application, I setup the set as start up page as index.cshtml in VS2015.

The same code will work in my local machine, like whenever I run the application it automatically load the index.cshtml page without any errors.

[image]

Before posting question here: I tried with these below options

1. Added index.cshtml under default documents section of web app. but it's not working.

Can you please tell me how to load the default page after published angular2 app into azure web app?

Comment: .cshtml is c# html files right? why are you using them in an angular web app?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Because I read the web.config settings. that's why I used the .cshtml extension.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon The same code will work when I run the application in local machine.

Comment: why not just have a config.ts file? or read the web.config in via ts

Comment: @mast3rd3mon because I used the web.config values in entire my application.

Comment: i gathered that, i still dont see why you dont read use a config.ts file or read it in via ts

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you could change `hostingstart.html` to `index.cshtml` in **Default documents** under **Application settings** via the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com) as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already tried with these option but it's not working.

Comment: Try to delete `hostingstart.html` from `/wwwroot` directory.